# Is the complement of {(a^nb^n)^m | n>0,m>0} context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I've been asked to decide whether a given language is CFL. If yes, I should find the grammar that creates it, and if not, I need to prove it (with the pumping lemma). 
The given language is the **complement** of the next language:
$L=\{(a^{n}b^{n})^{m} \mid n>0, m>0\}$. The alphabet is $\{a,b\}$.
I couldn't find any grammar that can create words of type $abaabb$ and also words of type $aabbb$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L=\left\{(a^nb^n)^m:n,m\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ and $L'=\{a,b\}^*\setminus\left\{(a^nb^n)^m:n,m\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$; we’re interested in whether $L'$ is context-free.

$L$ consists of those words having alternating blocks of $a$s and $b$s such that

- all of the blocks are the same positive length,
- the first block is a block of $a$s, and
- the last block is a block of $b$s.

From this characterization of $L$ it’s not hard to devise a test for membership in $L'$.

- The empty word $\epsilon$ is in $L'$.
- Every word that begins with $b$ or ends with $a$ is in $L'$.
- Every word that has a block of $a$s either immediately preceded or immediately followed by a block of $b$s of a different length is in $L'$. (By *block* I mean a maximal block: a string of consecutive $a$s or $b$s that cannot be extended to a longer such string.)
- And finally, every word in $L'$ is in at least one of these three categories.

It’s easy to design a context-free grammar that produces every word in the first two categories. The third category is also context-free. Here’s a start on it: the grammar fragment

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to XbaaAbaY\mid aaAbaY\mid XbaaAb\mid aaAb\\
&A\to aAb\mid aA\mid\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

generates strings of the following forms, where $n>m$: $Xba^nb^maY$, $a^nb^maY$, $Xba^nb^m$, and $a^nb^m$. Provided that you give $X$ and $Y$ the right productions, these are all of the ways to have a block of $a$s followed by a shorter block of $b$s.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. I didn't understand what is the purpose of X and Y in you grammar, if it is already ensured we got more a's than b's in some block. You added them so I could create any word that answer the characteristics? i.e X will be X--> bX | b, and Y--> aY | a.

Comment: @user3680924: I deliberately gave only a part of the grammar, leaving the rest for you to think about. What you’ve done with them isn’t enough: $X$ and $Y$ have to be able to generate every possible string of $a$s and $b$s, because (for instance) no matter what words $u$ and $v$ are, $ubaabav\in L'$. But even after you’ve fixed that, you still have some work to do: you have add something to the grammar to generate all words that have a block $a^nb^m$ where $n<m$.

Comment: Interestingly enough the language $L$ itself is not context free (showing that CFL is not closed under complement).

Comment: @MHS: Yes, it’s a nice example of that, since both facts are relatively easy to show.

Comment: @MHS : Could you clarify why $L$ is not context free. Or why the following grammar, does not generate $L$
$$
S \rightarrow SA | A 
$$

$$
A \rightarrow aAb | ab
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vigneshwaren: Your grammar does not respect the condition that all the $a^nb^n$ blocks have to have the same length $2n$ and in fact this is not possible to guarantee with a context free grammar. (Use the pumping lemma to check this. The idea is that a push down automaton that already checks that number of $a$'s is equal to number of $b$'s has not enough "memory" to reuse this length $n$ over and over. The argument is a bit like the standard $a^nb^nc^n$ example.)